# Setting MAMP to use port 80 gives the "The requested URL / was not found on this server." message but it works on port 8888

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, port, mamp

I'm having this issue with MAMP on OS X Mojave. When I change the ports to be default (`localhost:8888`) the WordPress (wp-config) screen.

This is what I'm expecting to load since I haven't set up my installation of WordPress yet, however when I change my port to 80 I get the following error message:

```
Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

Why does it work on the default port, but not on port 80? Is there a way to make port 80 work?

Comment: If you open up the terminal, what is the output of `curl -I http://localhost:80`?

Comment: @JakeGould The output that I get is:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 31 Mar 2019 02:06:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.3.1 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2o DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Did you ever play around with the location of your root document folder? I would recommend going to “Preferences” then choose the “Web Server” tab and confirm it’s where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

At guess, since MAMP runs on Apache, this may be a virtual host problem.

The main Apache installation (what's configured in `httpd.conf`) typically listens on one or more primary ports (i.e. port 80 and perhaps port 443). However, Apache [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) (which allow Apache to deliver multiple websites from one server) can listen on any port. So Apache may return a 404 if your virtual host for Wordpress is set up to listen on e.g. port 8888 (this is likely separate from any settings in Wordpress).

As a suggestion, have a look at e.g. `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and see if there are any virtual hosts that correspond to your Wordpress installation.

Comment: While there is truth to this answer, the thing is with MAMP, the Apache config is never really changed unless you explicitly set it as such. And many times, people, just adjust the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/httpd.conf` file instead of the individual config files.